# Python find indices of elements in one list that are not in the other list

Tags: python, list

```
list_1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
list_2 = ["a", "c", "d"]
```

I want the indices of elements in `list_1` that are not in `list_2`. Here I would expect

```
[1, 4]
```

For my case, `list_2` is a subset of `list_1` and all elements are unique. Is there a better way to do this without using explicit loops?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a conditional list comprehension:

```
>>> [i for i, item in enumerate(list_1) if item not in list_2]
[1, 4]
```

This solution has a time complexity of `O(n*m)`. For bigger lists, it makes sense to convert `list_2` to a `set` as it is much faster to search in a `set`. The following solution is `O(n)`:

```
>>> set_2 = set(list_2)
>>> [i for i, item in enumerate(list_1) if item not in set_2]
[1, 4]
```

Comment: Really nice answer. Short, right, including O-complexity. I'm satisfied. :)